# latex command for the symbol like UI

Tags: symbols

Hi I'm trying to code this symbol but I'm not getting the exact output, can anyone help me to code this symbol

[image]

i tried code `\cup|`

Comment: so it's kind of like `\subseteq` but rotated?

Comment: yes somewhat like tat, but im not getting exact output for this

Comment: Hi, you have asked several questions about finding symbols. Maybe you can state what these symbols do / where are they from? This way you can help others helping you finding the desired symbols. Thanks!

Comment: following up on what @Francis has said, there's more than one reason why it's helpful to know what a symbol is used for, and where you may have seen it in use.  as a representative to unicode from the stipub consortium, with suitable documentation i can submit "new" symbols to be considered for addition to unicode.  however, good documentation is needed, including published examples.

Comment: @ravi The symbol in the answer is not what you were looking for?

Answer (score 7):

Depending on the fact you want it as a binary *operator* or as a binary *relation*, you can try

```
\newcommand{\binsubseteq}{\mathbin{\text{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\subseteq$}}‌​}}
```

or

```
\newcommand{\relsubseteq}{\mathrel{\text{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\subseteq$}}‌​}}
```

They both require `amsmath` and `graphicx`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\binsubseteq}{\mathbin{\text{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\subseteq$}}}}
\newcommand{\relsubseteq}{\mathrel{\text{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\subseteq$}}}}

\begin{document}

\[
 A \binsubseteq B_{A \binsubseteq B_{A \binsubseteq B}}
\]

\[
 A \relsubseteq B_{A \relsubseteq B_{A \relsubseteq B}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]